# Two errors in my Angular factory/service using IE, but no errors in Chrome or Edge

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer, angular-services

**I am getting 2 errors in IE, that I am not getting in Chrome or Edge.**

It could be that it is a compatibility issue with the specific code and IE, or perhaps it is my code itself that is causing the errors.

**First error:**

*Syntax error (no specifics):* on this line of code:

```
var groupedArray = Object.keys(groupedObj).sort().map(key=>groupedObj[key]);
```

**Second error:**

*Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: GroupDateRangeServiceProvider <- GroupDateRangeService <- SocialMentionsAnalysisController*

Like I mentioned, I do not get these errors in Chrome, nor Edge, but I would prefer to make the site compatible with IE users.

**Below is the complete code of my Angular factory/service:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('portalDashboardApp')
        .factory('GroupDateRangeService', GroupDateRangeService);

    GroupDateRangeService.$inject = [];

    function GroupDateRangeService() {

        var service = {
            createArray: createArray,
            setItemCount: setItemCount,
            setSeries: setSeries
        };

        return service;

        function createArray(dateArray, valueArray) {
            var arr = dateArray.map(function (s) {
                var week = getWeekNumber(parseISOLocal(s));
                return week[0] + ('0' + week[1]).slice(-2) + ':' + s;
            }).sort();
            var results = createGroupedArray(createGroupObject(arr));
            if (valueArray && valueArray.length === dateArray.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    results[i] = results[i].map(function (date, index) {
                        var obj = {};
                        obj[date] = valueArray[index];

                        return obj;
                    });
                }
            }

            var arrayOfWeeks = results;
            return results;
        }

        // Create a Total Count
        function setItemCount(dataSet) {
            var itemCount = 0;
            angular.forEach(dataSet, function (dataItem) {
                itemCount = itemCount + dataItem.Total;
            });
            return itemCount;
        };

        // Create Chart Series
        function setSeries(dataSet, type) {
            var series = [{
                name: 'Items',
                data: [],
                showInLegend: false
            }];
            angular.forEach(dataSet, function (dataItem, dataIndex) {
                if (type === 'Count') {
                    series[0].data[dataIndex] = [dataItem.Description, dataItem.Total];
                }
                else if (type === 'Percentage') {
                    series[0].type = 'pie';
                    series[0].innerSize = '40%';
                    series[0].data[dataIndex] = [dataItem.Description, dataItem.Percentage];
                }
                else if (type === 'Adspend') {
                    series[0].data[dataIndex] = [dataItem.Description, dataItem.Adspend];
                }
            });
            return series;
        };

        function createGroupObject(arr) {

            var groupedObj = arr.reduce(function (result, value) {

                var b = value.split(':');

                if (!result[b[0]]) result[b[0]] = [];
                result[b[0]].push(b[1]);

                return result;

            }, {});

            return groupedObj;
        }

        function createGroupedArray(groupedObj) {

            // Grab arrays in order of week number. Sort keys to maintain order
            var groupedArray = Object.keys(groupedObj).sort().map(key=>groupedObj[key]);

            // Final set of grouped dates
            console.log(groupedArray.join('\n\n'));

            return groupedArray;

        }

        /* Helper to get the ISO week number of a date
        ** @param {Date} date to get week of
        ** @returns {Array} [year, weekNumber]
        */
        function getWeekNumber(d) {
            d = new Date(+d);
            d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - (d.getDay() || 7));
            var yearStart = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
            var weekNo = Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7);
            return [d.getFullYear(), weekNo];
        }

        /* Parse ISO 8601 format date string to local date
        ** @param {string} s - string to parse like 2016-12-15
        ** @returns {Date}
        */
        function parseISOLocal(s) {
            var b = s.split(/\D/);
            return new Date(b[0], b[1] - 1, b[2]);
        }
    }

})();
```

I would appreciate some guidance!

Comment: I don't get it. You write that you want your code to be compatible with IE, yet you deliberately use technology that has been introduced long after IE. How do you explain this contradiction?

Comment: Hi  zeroflagL, are you referring to the use of Angular, or a specific line of code? My whole project works in IE, it is only this 2 errors I picked up today, in a new method and service I created. That is why I am asking for direction on how to fix this. I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: You use ES2015 (`key=>groupedObj[key]`), which has been introduced two years after the last version of IE, not to mention older versions.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I did think that that was the issue. Do you perhaps have a suggestion on rewriting that line in an acceptable version of JavaScript? That would be the winner. :D

Comment: `function(key) { return groupedObj[key]; }`

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the solution thanks to zeroflagL:**

My issue was the use of ES2015 JavaScript code in my service/factory. This is incomparable with IE, that has not had a new release in 2 years.

**So, changing**

```
var groupedArray = Object.keys(groupedObj).sort()
    .map(key=>groupedObj[key]);
```

**to:**

```
var groupedArray = Object.keys(groupedObj).sort()
    .map(function (key) {
        return groupedObj[key];
    });
```

solved both my errors!